# How to Plot Line Chart in JavaFX with selected column values from database?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

1. Suppose I have 40 Columns in table
2. I created one Scene where I put 40 checkboxes to select the columns
3. Suppose I checked only 15 columns to see a line chart plot with respect to another value.

How can I do this using JavaFX?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] of what you've got so far?

Comment: Learn about TableView or ListView. I am leaning toward TableView. Add you data and the CheckBox to each row. Add a listener to the CheckBox that grabs the row data and creates a series to be added to the Chart. You could also use ListView with multiple row select enabled. In this case, each time you select a row, create a series to be added to the Chart.

Comment: Your Excel data and the way it is plotted on the chart is confusing. I would have Parameters in the column where ObjX are. I would have the data associated with the ParameterX on the same row. And my headers would be objX.